# Microbit truncates messages received from LoRa Reyax RYLR890/896 module

Tags: javascript, lora, bbc-microbit

I have set up a MicroBit as a LoRa receiver using a LoRa module from Reyax RYLR890/896. These LoRa modules receive/transmit information with AT commands over the serial port.

On the transmitter, I have an ESP32 that I have programmed in C in the Arduino framework. It is wired to a Reyax RYLR890 module and transmits a message every few seconds with an 'AT+SEND' command. I have verified that it transmits correctly with another Reyax RYLR890 module set up as receiver in the following ways:

1. Hooked up to my Macbook's USB port via FTDI adapter to convert between UART and USB serial protocols. I use the CoolTerm serial monitor to see the received messages.
2. Wired to another ESP32 connected my Macbook's USB port. I can see the received messages in the serial monitor in PlatformIO.

The transmissions are correctly sent and received in both cases.

Now I set up reception on a Microbit using two pins (14, 15) for serial redirect. I am able to receive transmissions but they are truncated for some reason. Instead of "Hello World", I only see "Hello W". Here is my code:

```
let preamble = ""
let comma_first = 0
let generic_message = ""
let comma_second = 0
let sizeTx = 0
let payload = ""
let messageRx = ""

input.onButtonPressed(Button.A, function () {
    serial.redirect(
    SerialPin.P15,
    SerialPin.P14,
    BaudRate.BaudRate9600
    )
    basic.showIcon(IconNames.Yes)
})

function parseRx (message: string) {
    // message: "+RCV=120,11,HELLO WORLD,-99,40\n"
    preamble = message.substr(1, 3)
    if (preamble == "RCV") { // Check
        // Play tone
        music.playTone(262, music.beat(BeatFraction.Whole))
        // Find 1st comma
        comma_first = message.indexOf(",")
        // Get "11,HELLO WORLD,-99,40\n"
        generic_message = message.substr(comma_first + 1, message.length - comma_first)
        // Find next comma
        comma_second = generic_message.indexOf(",")
        // Extract size of payload and use it to get payload
        sizeTx = parseFloat(generic_message.substr(0, comma_second)) // 11
        payload = generic_message.substr(comma_second + 1, sizeTx) // HELLO WORLD
        // Display 
        basic.showString("" + (payload.length))
        if (payload.includes("WOR")) { // FAILS!! HELLO W
            basic.showIcon(IconNames.SmallHeart)
        }
    }
}

serial.onDataReceived(serial.delimiters(Delimiters.NewLine), function () {
    messageRx = serial.readUntil(serial.delimiters(Delimiters.NewLine))
    parseRx(messageRx)
    basic.clearScreen()
    basic.showIcon(IconNames.Happy)
    basic.clearScreen()
})
```

I appreciate any help figuring this out.

Comment: It appears that this is a problem with `serial.demliters()` and delimiters are not aligning. The transmission is terminated by CRLF (Carriage Return + Line Feed). The AT command is 'AT+SEND=0,11,HELLO WORLD\r\n'. The message is received as '+RCV=120,11,HELLO WORD,-99,40\n' where 120 is transmitter address, 11 is length of the payload, HELLO WORLD is the payload, and the remaining information pertains to signal strength and Signal-Noise ratio. When I query the length of the rec'd message at serial, it is 19, which is ''+RCV=120,11,HELLO W'. Somehow the delimiters don't align.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the buffer size and the serial trigger fires an event either when it finds a delimiter or when the buffer is full: https://github.com/lancaster-university/microbit-dal/blob/master/source/drivers/MicroBitSerial.cpp. Any way to workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the size of the serial buffer was the issue that was the root cause of incoming radio transmissions being truncated. The default size is 20 Bytes ([here](https://github.com/lancaster-university/microbit-dal/blob/602153e9199c28c08fd2561ce7b43bf64e9e7394/inc/drivers/MicroBitSerial.h#LL33C9-L33C44)) and triggers an event when 20 Bytes are rec'd ([here](https://github.com/lancaster-university/microbit-dal/blob/master/source/drivers/MicroBitSerial.cpp)).

The fix turned out to be to increase the buffer size. This additional line of code `serial.setRxBufferSize(128)` did the job. Ref. [docs](https://makecode.microbit.org/reference/serial/set-rx-buffer-size).

```
let preamble = ""
let comma_first = 0
let generic_message = ""
let comma_second = 0
let sizeTx = 0
let payload = ""
let messageRx = ""
input.onButtonPressed(Button.A, function () {
    serial.redirect(
    SerialPin.P15,
    SerialPin.P14,
    BaudRate.BaudRate9600
    )
    serial.setRxBufferSize(128)
    basic.showIcon(IconNames.Yes)
})
function parseRx (message: string) {
    preamble = message.substr(1, 3)
    if (preamble == "RCV") {
        music.playTone(988, music.beat(BeatFraction.Whole))
        comma_first = message.indexOf(",")
        generic_message = message.substr(comma_first + 1, message.length - comma_first)
        comma_second = generic_message.indexOf(",")
        sizeTx = parseFloat(generic_message.substr(0, comma_second))
        payload = generic_message.substr(comma_second + 1, sizeTx)
        basic.showString("" + (payload.length))
        if (payload.includes("WOR")) {
            basic.showIcon(IconNames.SmallHeart)
        }
    }
}
serial.onDataReceived(serial.delimiters(Delimiters.NewLine), function () {
    messageRx = serial.readUntil(serial.delimiters(Delimiters.NewLine))
    parseRx(messageRx)
    basic.clearScreen()
    basic.showIcon(IconNames.Happy)
    basic.clearScreen()
})
```

[image]